# Using struct as SSE vector type in gcc?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, sse

Is it possible in GCC to use a struct or class as a vector type for SSE instructions?

something like:

```
typedef struct vfloat __attribute__((vector_size(16))) {
   float x,y,z,w;
} vfloat;
```

Rather than the canonical:

```
typedef float v4sf __attribute__ ((vector_size(16)));

union vfloat {
    v4sf  v;
    float f[4];
};
```

Would be very handy, but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: WHen you say you "can't seem to make it work", what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: The syntax just doesn't work, gcc gives me "error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you make a `union` like the one you posted but with your `struct` instead of `float f[4];` as the second member?  That would give you the behavior you want.

Comment: The idea is I'd like to be able to write functions (particularly operators) on the vector type, and having to access the vector differently through a union depending on what I want to do is pretty inelegant IMHO, it's not just a matter of naming.

Comment: Why not change make `vfloat` the `union` type and then use some other internal name for the actual `struct` underneath?  That way you can pass around objects with that `union` type just like you are with the structs now.  Look up "transparent union" to make the interface even nicer.

Comment: Hmm hadn't heard of a transparent union before, that may be what I have to do.

Comment: @gct: You can also check the "Unnamed struct/union fields within structs/unions" page in the GCC documentation.  Transparent unions are even more transparent, though, allowing you to pass your `struct` as the `union`.  Be careful about alignment in that case, though.  You might want to make sure your `struct` has the same alignment as is required for the vector.

Answer (score 0):

The structure you seem be looking for is

```
typedef float  v4sf __attribute__ ((vector_size(16)));
typedef struct vfloat  vfloat;

struct vfloat {
    union {
        v4sf       v;
        float      f[4];
        struct {
            float  x;
            float  y;
            float  z;
            float  w;
        };
    };
};
```

However, the aliasing rules may bite you later on in the future. I recommend using accessor macros or `static inline` functions instead.